# regex for phone number format xxx.xxx.xxxx exactly?

Tags: regex

Can somebody give me the regex for validating the phone number in the format 
xxx.xxx.xxxx exactly(three digits and a dot and three digits and a dot and four digits)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Answer (score 7):

```
^\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{4}$
```

Answer (score 2):

```
^(\d{3}\.){2}\d{4}$
```

Comment: I think you did a typo - it should be 3 instead of 2, and I don't think it will match properly on the last expected .